# Play random audio using http request (Ionic 2)

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am creating a ionic 2 soundboard app that uses http requests to load .mp3 files from a server. The mp3's are then displayed in my soundboard.html page in the form of buttons.

What I am trying to do is create a button that when clicked calls a function that **randomly** plays a mp3 file.

I think the solution is simple im just not getting any ideas on how to do this.

**soundboard.ts**

```
constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http.get(this.base_url + this.sounds_url)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          /* Create a webpage out of the data from the http.get request */
          let content: string = data.text();
          let doc: any = document.createElement("html");
          doc.innerHTML = content;

          /* Extract all "a" tags from it */
          let links: any = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");

          /* Loop through them, saving their title and sound file */
          for(let link of links) {            
            let filename = link.getAttribute("href")

            this.sounds.push({
              title: link.innerHTML,
              file: filename

            });
          }
        },
        err => console.error('There was an error: ' + err),
        () => console.log('Get request completed')
       );
     }


/* Plays a sound, pausing other playing sounds if necessary */
  play(sound) {
    console.log(sound)
    if(this.media) {
      this.media.pause();
    }
    this.media = new Audio(sound.file);
    this.media.load();
    this.media.play();
  }
```

**soundboard.html**

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row wrap>
    <ion-col  ng-repeat *ngFor="let sound of sounds" width-33>
    <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content (click)="play(sound)">          
        <img src="{{ sound.imageUrl }}" /> 
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>  
    </ion-col>    
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: Is the code above working properly?

Comment: I.e. all the values are getting updated in sounds array. Check that first on `console` via `console.log()`. If yes then creating a button on clicking playing a random sound of these sounds is easy right? Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length());` to create a random index.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni I already have a button that when clicked plays a sound (I added the code in my question)

where do i add the code you suggested?

Comment: Hey the code `Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length());` is for choosing a random index number in an array of sounds. Access the sound at that index however you want. What are you passing as `sound` in `play(sound)`? I will add an answer to this if I have understood this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is your random button in html:

```
<button (click)="playRandom()">Random Sound</button>
```

In your .ts:

```
playRandom(){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length());
    play(sounds[index]);
}
```

And this should work.

Comment: Work around other things around your code via debugging if it does not work as expected. Also, this is just a template code. Style the button as you want.

Comment: Sagar, do you have a skype?

Comment: Try this out and let me know where the problem is. Why do we need skype?